# Включение ссылок на сборки .Net в UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Возникло затруднение с включением ссылок на сборки определенные в стандартной библиотеке в приложении UWP. В консольном приложении я мог просто добавить ссылку на интересующую сборку, например System.Runtime.Serialization.dll. В приложении UWP эти сборки не отображаются.

Как можно решить эту проблему?

**UPD:** В недавнем обновлении .Net Core, была возвращена сериализация объектов по типу .Net Standart.

Comment: UWP != .Net Framework. Ответ: никак.

Comment: @Сергей Как это, никак? А как производится работа с JSON на платформе UWP?

Comment: @АртёмКиргизов: Возьмите JSON.NET.

Comment: @VladD то есть? Его где то нужно докачивать?

Comment: Качается студией через NuGet